# how to detect a new application being launched from C#?

Tags: c#

I have a .dll library for c# that loves to pop out a 'Welcome' screen when it starts.
This screen appears as an application in the task manager.

[image]

Is there some way to automatically detect this application/form being launched and close it?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848618/net-events-for-process-executable-start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's running within your process and opening a Form (not a Dialog), you can use something like this to close all Forms which aren't opened by your own Assembly.

```
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
    if (form.GetType().Assembly != typeof(Program).Assembly)
        form.Close();
```

What is your own Assembly is defined by the class `Program`, you could also use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` or `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly`, but I'm not sure it will behave correctly, if you run the Application inside Visual Studio (since it might return the VS Assembly).

Comment: IT WORKS! Currently I hooked it onto a timer and made if (form.Text == "Welcome"){ form.Close(); } and it closes ok. :) Just one more thing, how do I detect that a new form is being open, so that I would run this when a form is created, no by timer? :)

Comment: Running this on a timer is not pretty, yes. You should be able to track down the source of the form opening and just close it directly afterwards. There could be possibilities of getting a [callback on form opening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603600/winforms-is-there-a-way-to-be-informed-whenever-a-form-gets-opened-in-my-applica), but I think i tried something like that before and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Here us simple console application that will monitor and close specified window

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            FindAndKill("Welcome");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private static void FindAndKill(string caption)
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            IntPtr pFoundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;           
            StringBuilder windowText = new StringBuilder(256);

            GetWindowText(pFoundWindow, windowText, windowText.Capacity);
            if (windowText.ToString() == caption)
            {
                p.CloseMainWindow();
                Console.WriteLine("Excellent kill !!!");
            }
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowText",ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd,StringBuilder lpWindowText, int nMaxCount);
}
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine("MMMMMMONSTER KILL!"); =P

Comment: MMMMMMONSTER KILL! :) * thumbs up *

Comment: Thanks for the code, i'll check it out! by the way, should I add the user32.dll as a reference?

Comment: user32.dll it's native windows dll. You cant add it like reference

Comment: I think this is not going to work, because the "Welcome" dialog most likely is not running in its own process but in yours.

Comment: oh, then how do I add this .dll ? :/
Yes, it is running within my process, i.e. no new processes appear when it pops out.

Comment: dont add it. `DllImport` will find it

Comment: nope, it says Error 5 The type or namespace name 'DllImport' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: In order to use `DllImport` add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`