# .NET Application.OpenForms collection changing

Tags: c#, .net

How can I catch Application.OpenForms collection changing event? I want add/remove items — forms names from list when this collection changed.
.NET 2.0

Comment: As far as I know that's not possible. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603600/winforms-is-there-a-way-to-be-informed-whenever-a-form-gets-opened-in-my-applic) can help you further?

Comment: Glad I could help ;-) I've put it in an answer for others comming to this page.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible, but you can use one of the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603600/winforms-is-there-a-way-to-be-informed-whenever-a-form-gets-opened-in-my-applic) question.